# Xamarin - Bulk change ContentPage to an inherited Content Page?

Tags: xamarin

I have a medium sized project with around 50-100 ContentPages.

I've created an CustomContentPage class which inherits from ContentPage and I want to change all my content pages to CustomContentPage.

I can do a simple find and replace of ": ContentPage" to ": CustomContentPage", but having trouble with the XAML side, especially on the opening tags "<ContentPage"

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: “Having trouble” is not a useful description of the problem.  What have you tried and what specific problem are you having?

Comment: I don't think there is another way other than doing a couple of "find and replace" operations and adjusting the XML namespaces.